# Podman images not showing with podman image ls

Tags: centos, containers, rhel, podman

I am trying to setup a build server in a Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 (CentoOS 8) virtual machine.

I installed podman by running `sudo dnf install -y @container-tools`

I then ran `sudo podman pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim` to pull a container image from docker:

> Trying to pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim...Getting image source signatures
>   Copying blob e936bd534ffb done
>   Copying blob caf64655bcbb done
>   Copying blob 4156e490f05f done
>   Copying blob 68ced04f60ab done
>   Copying blob 7064c3d93b4a done
>   Copying config e2cd20adb1 done
>   Writing manifest to image destination
>   Storing signatures
>   e2cd20adb1292ef24ca70de7abaddaadd57a5c932d3852b972e43b6f05a03dea

This looks successful to me.  And if I run it again, I get told that the layers "already exists".  But then I run:

```
podman image ls
```

and I get an empty list back:

> REPOSITORY   TAG   IMAGE ID   CREATED   SIZE

I also tried the following commands to get a list:

- `podman image ls -a`
- `podman image list`
- `podman image list -a`
- `podman images`
- `podman images ls`
- `podman images ls -a`
- `podman images list`
- `podman images list -a`

They all give an empty list.

**How can I see the container image that I pulled down?**

Update: I ran `sudo podman run --rm --name=linuxconfig-test -p 80:80 httpd` and (on another machine) browsed to the ip address of my linux machine and got `It Works!` shown.  So podman is working at least in part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you have to run using `sudo`.  I ran :

```
sudo podman image ls
```

and it returned the list of container images.

Comment: Also, if you'd like to get more information about how Podman is configured per user, you can run `podman info` which, among other lines, will have something like: `graphRoot: /home/<user>/.local/share/containers/storage` for a rootless user. It can be overriden by modifying `/home/<user>/.config/containers/storage.conf`, example file in located in `/etc/containers/storage.conf`.

Answer (score 10):

Unlike Docker, Podman stores images in the home directory of the user. The default path is `~/.local/share/containers/storage` and it can be verified by running `podman info`. Since you executed `podman pull` as root, the pulled image will be stored in the home directory of the root user. This is why no images are listed when you run `podman image ls` without `sudo`.

The main idea behind podman is that it can run entirely in user mode without connecting to a priviledged daemon. Ideally, all podman commands should be run without `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem after pulling a local image from the local Docker.

The pull was successful, and Podman stopped displaying any images after that.

Executing `sudo podman image ls` also returned an empty list, but it magically resolved the regular `podman image ls` under my current user, and all images (including the new one pulled from the Docker) started displaying.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `--root` option to give the path to where the images are stored. That is if you need to run as root.

Though one important part of using podman is that you do not need to run as root or sudo user.

Note - The moment you run this, podman will change the owner of certain folders and files in the overlay location,and later when you run without `sudo` , you need to `chown` back. So not recommended

```
sudo podman images --root  /home/xxx/.local/share/containers/storage
```